# Oracle SQL WHERE CASE IN statement with 3 outputs

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a small piece of code that has a parameter input in the front end.

The options for input are either yes, no & all which equate to:

```
yes = TRUE
no = FALSE
all = TRUE & FALSE
```

My code is:

```
SELECT c.ID, 
c.rep, 
c.cust
FROM mytable c 
WHERE '&input' IN (
CASE WHEN 'yes' THEN c.Acc = 'TRUE'
     WHEN 'no' THEN c.Acc = 'FALSE'
     WHEN 'all' THEN c.Acc IN ('TRUE', 'FALSE')
END)
```

But getting the error:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR`

```
SELECT c.ID, 
    c.rep, 
    c.cust
FROM mytable c 
WHERE (&input = 'yes' and c.Acc = 'TRUE') OR
      (&input = 'no' and c.Acc = 'FALSE') OR
      (&input = 'all' and c.Acc IN ('TRUE', 'FALSE'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.rep, c.cust
FROM mytable c 
WHERE (c.Acc =  = &input OR &input = 'all')
```

Comment: c.Acc cannot equal the input as they are different values in the DB. the data has TRUE or FALSE, the inputs can be yes, no or all